# Is NightmareJS (electron browser) compatible Firebase Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nightmare

I have an app that takes a New York Times recipe URL, and converts the list of ingredients into a shopping to-do list.

Because the New York Times uses React, none of the data is available via standard scraping - the index.html is mostly blank. I have to use a library like NightmareJS, which uses an Electron browser to fully construct the DOM (including the Javascript) so that I can then scrape that constructed-DOM for data.

But this doesn't seem to work. Here's the code I have included in my /functions/index.js file:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const Actions = require('nightmare-react-utils').Actions

exports.listify = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  console.log("YOU ARE NOW INSIDE THE LISTIFY FUNCTION!")

  Nightmare.action(...Actions)
  const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: false })
  const selector = 'ul.recipe-ingredients'
  const queryUrl = req.query.url
  nightmare
    .goto(queryUrl)
    .wait()
    .evaluate((selector) => {

      console.log("YOU ARE NOW INSIDE THE EVALUATE!")

      const recipeIngredientsObject = document.querySelector(selector).children
      const result = []

      const ingredientKeys = Object.keys(recipeIngredientsObject)
      ingredientKeys.forEach((key) => {
      const ingredientObject = recipeIngredientsObject[key]
      const quantityAndIngredient = ingredientObject.children
      result.push({
          "quantity": quantityAndIngredient[0].innerText,
          "ingredient": quantityAndIngredient[1].innerText
      })
    })
    return result
  }, selector)
})
```

When I call this Function from my front-end, I see the first console log in my Firebase logs - "YOU ARE NOW INSIDE THE LISTIFY FUNCTION!" - but I do not see the second message: "YOU ARE NOW INSIDE THE EVALUATE!"

Can I not use NightmareJS with Firebase Functions?

Comment: What payment plan is your Firebase project on?

Comment: I'm on the "Blaze" plan, which is Firebase's pay-as-you-go plan.

Comment: Does it work if you run locally using `firebase serve`?

Comment: How did you solve this? Does Nightmare work at all inside a Cloud Function? Will it have to install the Electron browser everytime your function runs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The console.log message will never appear. When you run evaluate, that function is executed inside the context of the headless browser, so will not log to terminal.

Try something like...

```
.evaluate((selector) => {
    return document.querySelector(selector)
}, selector)
.end()
.then(console.log)
```

To see if it's working at all.